# When only using HTTPSProxy in torrc, will also directory requests get routed through that proxy?

Tags: configuration, pre-tor-proxy

[It's not possible to use Tor behind a http-only proxy (not supporting the "connect" method.](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/218/how-to-use-tor-behind-a-http-only-proxy)

[Tor's manual says:](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en)

> **HTTPProxy host[:port]**
>
> Tor will make all its directory requests through this host:port (or host:80 if port is not specified), rather than connecting directly to any directory servers.
>
> **HTTPSProxy host[:port]**
>
> Tor will make all its OR (SSL) connections through this host:port (or host:443 if port is not specified), via HTTP CONNECT rather than connecting directly to servers. You may want to set FascistFirewall to restrict the set of ports you might try to connect to, if your HTTPS proxy only allows connecting to certain ports.

When one is only using HTTPSProxy, will also directory requests get routed through that proxy?

When one's goal is to route all of Tor's traffic through that proxy is it required to use HTTPProxy and HTTPSProxy or is using HTTPSProxy alone sufficient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nowadays, normal clients always tunnel their directory requests over one-hop Tor connection by default.

The [TunnelDirConns](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en) configuration option specifies that behavior and it has defaulted to tunneling since about 2008 ([svn revision 13935](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/commitdiff/0df15642980fd050ff7e77a311b03c6b5e4ef8dc)).

Accordingly, if you are just a client and not a relay or bridge relay, setting HTTPSProxy should be all that's needed.

Comment: http://tor.stackexchange.com/a/296/58 mentions some properties of tunneled directory connections.