# Set a tor server behind http proxy

Tags: configuration, proxy, error, dns, https

I'm trying to make a tor relay server over a http proxy on a ubuntu 14.04 lts machine.

Log output:

```
$ cat /var/log/tor/log
Aug 17 18:19:06.000 [notice] Tor 0.2.4.27 (git-412e3f7dc9c6c01a) opening new log file.
Aug 17 18:19:06.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv4 file /usr/share/tor/geoip.
Aug 17 18:19:07.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv6 file /usr/share/tor/geoip6.
Aug 17 18:19:08.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server.
Aug 17 18:20:43.000 [notice] Interrupt: exiting cleanly.
Aug 17 18:20:45.000 [notice] Tor 0.2.4.27 (git-412e3f7dc9c6c01a) opening log file.
Aug 17 18:20:45.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv4 file /usr/share/tor/geoip.
Aug 17 18:20:45.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv6 file /usr/share/tor/geoip6.
Aug 17 18:20:45.000 [notice] Configured to measure statistics. Look for the *-stats files that will first be written to the data directory in 24 hours from now.
Aug 17 18:20:46.000 [notice] Your Tor server's identity key fingerprint is 'ididntedittheconfig 511FBDFE23658FB9C76695C2251753ED22F4D054'
Aug 17 18:23:56.000 [warn] eventdns: All nameservers have failed
$
```

My network settings are correct,i can connect to internet:

computer > router > http_proxy > internet

My torrc after correction looks like that:

```
HTTPSProxy 192.168.x.x:44355

ORPort 443
Exitpolicy reject *:*
Nickname ididntedittheconfig
ContactInfo human@...
```

DNS settings:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf  
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.0.1
$
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all that isn't how you make Tor use an HTTP proxy.

> HTTPProxy host[:port]
>
> Tor will make all its **directory requests** through this host:port (or host:80 if port is not specified), **rather than connecting directly to any directory servers**.

The option you probably want is this one

> HTTPSProxy host[:port]
>
> Tor will make all its **OR (SSL) connections** through this host:port (or host:443 if port is not specified), via HTTP CONNECT rather than connecting directly to servers. You may want to set FascistFirewall to restrict the set of ports you might try to connect to, if your HTTPS proxy only allows connecting to certain ports.

Second of all, you can't make it be a relay over a proxy, you're going to have to have port 443 exposed so that users trying to connect to your relay can connect to your `ORPort`.

Comment: thanks for answering,if i understand the right option is the HTTPS one?Also are you saying that it's impossible to make a relay over a proxy or dangerous? If i understand this [related topic](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/218/how-to-use-tor-behind-a-http-only-proxy?rq=1),it's not dangerous to have port 443 exposed as long as its for HTTPS only.

Comment: Proxy is for outbound connections, generally its for clients who are on networks that require the use of some gateway proxy to access any resources outside of the local network. Relays need to be accessible from the internet, clients do not. Are you sure it's a relay that you want to run?

Comment: I used the HTTPS option,still the same result,any idea?

Comment: Provide a full log output, please.

Comment: tor log file added.

Comment: What does your DNS config look like? Generally speaking Tor doesn't use DNS but you did mention you'd changed your DNS settings?

Comment: For some people changing dns settings solved the problem,so i did that too. Anyway, if i change dns settings or not there's always the same warning. dns config added.

Comment: What does your DNS config look like?

Comment: I just changed dns via nm-applet,see my edit

Comment: `cat /etc/resolv.conf` also this whole thing is just a `[warn]`, which should be non-fatal.

Comment: resolv.conf file added.

Comment: Maybe it should be non-fatal but because of this warning the server isn't operational.

Comment: So your localhost DNS server isn't working, I guess. Tor doesn't use DNS unless you're an exit so it won't affect you but if you want to investigate your DNS, look into whatever local DNS server you're running.